# Why is dynamic SQL not allowed in stored functions?

Tags: mysql, dynamic-sql, database-trigger, stored-functions

There are a lot of questions on SO and threads elsewhere on the web about `Dynamic SQL not allowed in stored functions or triggers` error message.  I get it: not allowed, no workaround, no solution - get lost.

What I am interested in is the reason for this.  Why are they not allowed?

Answer (score 0):

Because local variables are in scope only during stored program execution, references to them are not permitted in prepared statements created within a stored program.

Prepared statement scope is the current session, not the stored program, so the statement could be executed after the program ends, at which point the variables would no longer be in scope.